# How many devices can a Raspberry Pi provide power to?

Tags: power

I am planning to start a project, but the project heavily depends on it's mobility so I did not buy anything yet. But I am wondering, how many external devices can a raspberry pi provide power to? The project will include a 7" touchscreen (official from RPi website) bluetooth module (or mini usb dongle, If I can pair with two devices simultaneously or else I will have two of these ), gps antenna, small low res camera and an FM receiver.

Will the RPi be able to support all these?

Comment: could the downvoter care to say why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Pis with the 40 pin expansion header have a 2 amp polyfuse.  The earlier Pis have a 1 amp polyfuse.

So if you power the Pi via the microUSB socket those are the limits to be shared between the Pi and any attached devices.

You will need to find the current requirements of each device you wish to attach and estimate the likely usage of the Pi itself (which will vary with load).